# 'generate' is not a member of 'std::random_device' inside window's <random> header file

Tags: c++

So this application is giving me a compilation error **inside** random and I tried everything to fix it short of formatting my hard drive and reinstalling windows.

First time in a long time working with C++ (usually a .net guy) so I figured you lovely people might have an answer to this.

Code in question (remember, this is inside random)

```
// CLASS TEMPLATE mersenne_twister_engine
template <class _Ty, size_t _Wx, size_t _Nx, size_t _Mx, size_t _Rx, _Ty _Px, size_t _Ux, _Ty _Dx, size_t _Sx, _Ty _Bx,
    size_t _Tx, _Ty _Cx, size_t _Lx, _Ty _Fx>
class mersenne_twister_engine : public mersenne_twister<_Ty, _Wx, _Nx, _Mx, _Rx, _Px, _Ux, _Sx, _Bx, _Tx, _Cx, _Lx> {
public:
    static constexpr unsigned long long _Max = (((1ULL << (_Wx - 1)) - 1) << 1) + 1;

    _RNG_REQUIRE_UINTTYPE(mersenne_twister_engine, _Ty);

    static_assert(0 < _Mx && _Mx <= _Nx && 2U < _Wx && _Rx <= _Wx && _Ux <= _Wx && _Sx <= _Wx && _Tx <= _Wx
                      && _Lx <= _Wx && _Wx <= numeric_limits<_Ty>::digits && _Px <= _Max && _Bx <= _Max && _Cx <= _Max
                      && _Dx <= _Max && _Fx <= _Max,
        "invalid template argument for mersenne_twister_engine");

    using _Mybase     = mersenne_twister<_Ty, _Wx, _Nx, _Mx, _Rx, _Px, _Ux, _Sx, _Bx, _Tx, _Cx, _Lx>;
    using result_type = _Ty;

    static constexpr size_t word_size              = _Wx;
    static constexpr size_t state_size             = _Nx;
    static constexpr size_t shift_size             = _Mx;
    static constexpr size_t mask_bits              = _Rx;
    static constexpr _Ty xor_mask                  = _Px;
    static constexpr size_t tempering_u            = _Ux;
    static constexpr _Ty tempering_d               = _Dx;
    static constexpr size_t tempering_s            = _Sx;
    static constexpr _Ty tempering_b               = _Bx;
    static constexpr size_t tempering_t            = _Tx;
    static constexpr _Ty tempering_c               = _Cx;
    static constexpr size_t tempering_l            = _Lx;
    static constexpr _Ty initialization_multiplier = _Fx;

    static constexpr result_type default_seed = 5489U;

    explicit mersenne_twister_engine(result_type _X0 = default_seed) : _Mybase(_X0, _Dx, _Fx) {}

    template <class _Seed_seq, _Enable_if_seed_seq_t<_Seed_seq, mersenne_twister_engine> = 0>
    explicit mersenne_twister_engine(_Seed_seq& _Seq) : _Mybase(default_seed, _Dx, _Fx) {
        seed(_Seq);
    }

    void seed(result_type _X0 = default_seed) { // set initial values from specified value
        _Mybase::seed(_X0, _Fx);
    }

    template <class _Seed_seq, _Enable_if_seed_seq_t<_Seed_seq, mersenne_twister_engine> = 0>
    void seed(_Seed_seq& _Seq) { // reset sequence from seed sequence
        constexpr int _Kx = (_Wx + 31) / 32;
        unsigned long _Arr[_Kx * _Nx];
        _Seq.generate(&_Arr[0], &_Arr[_Kx * _Nx]);

        int _Idx0 = 0;
        _Ty _Sum  = 0;
        for (size_t _Ix = 0; _Ix < _Nx; ++_Ix, _Idx0 += _Kx) { // pack _Kx words
            this->_Ax[_Ix] = _Arr[_Idx0];
            for (int _Jx = 0; ++_Jx < _Kx;) {
                this->_Ax[_Ix] |= static_cast<_Ty>(_Arr[_Idx0 + _Jx]) << (32 * _Jx);
            }

            this->_Ax[_Ix] &= this->_WMSK;

            if (_Ix == 0) {
                _Sum = this->_Ax[_Ix] >> _Rx;
            } else {
                _Sum |= this->_Ax[_Ix];
            }
        }

        if (_Sum == 0) {
            this->_Ax[0] = this->_WMSK;
        }

        this->_Idx = _Nx;
    }

    _NODISCARD static constexpr result_type(min)() {
        return 0;
    }

    _NODISCARD static constexpr result_type(max)() {
        return _Mybase::_WMSK;
    }
};
```

The line in question:

`_Seq.generate(&_Arr[0], &_Arr[_Kx * _Nx]);`

How random is being used:

```
std::mt19937 seed;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist;

void SetLargeRand() // OK
{
    seed = std::mt19937(std::random_device());
    dist = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>(0,2147483647);
}

long GetLargeRand() // OK
{
    return dist(seed);
}
```

Thank you so much.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show *your* code that causes the failure to appear, in the form of a [mcve]. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). In short, the problem is unlikely to be in the standard library code, but rather because something you have done in your code.

Comment: "_is throwing an error_" - no, you get a **compilation** error. Copy/paste it as-is.

Comment: @TedLyngmo you are correct, it is a compilation error. I apologize for the confusion. I will edit the question to show how this code is being used.

Answer (score 12):

Minimal code that produces error from title

```cpp
#include<random>
int random_function()
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,10);
    static std::random_device rd;
    static auto mt = std::mt19937(rd);
//                                ^ Error here
    return dist(mt);
}


#include<iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout<<random_function()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Minimal code that fixes error

```cpp
#include<random>
int random_function()
{
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,10);
    static std::random_device rd;
    static auto mt = std::mt19937(rd());
//                                  ^ Fix here
    return dist(mt);
}
    

#include<iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout<<random_function()<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

So in the context of the OP's code,

```cpp
    seed = std::mt19937(std::random_device());
```

should be changed to

```cpp
    seed = std::mt19937(std::random_device()());
```

This is because random_device is a functor that returns what mt19937 wants.
Constructing one isn't enough, calling it is what is required.
Thus this constructs, calls, and destructs; the random_device functor, all in one go.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want overload number 3 from [this `std::mt19937` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/mersenne_twister_engine/mersenne_twister_engine)?

You're not supposed to pass a [`std::random_device`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) object there (in fact, you're using a non-portable Visual Studio extension that allows you to pass temporary objects as non-const references) but a reference to an object that can `generate` a random value.

You either have to come up with your own that follows the [SeedSequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/SeedSequence) requirements, or use the standard [`std::seed_seq`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/seed_seq) class.

Or, better yet, rely on the standard seed which will be more than adequate for almost all situations.

So you don't really need the `SetLargeRand` function at all, just the definitions:

```
std::mt19937 seed;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0,2147483647);
```